# Can I automatically change my PYTHONPATH when activating/deactivating a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I would like to have a different PYTHONPATH from my usual in a particular virtualenv. How do I set this up automatically? I realize that it's possible to hack the `bin/activate` file, is there a better/more standard way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [django-users post](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/5316bd02d34b7544) is probably going to help you a lot. It suggests using [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to wrap virtualenv, to use the [add2virtualenv](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#path-management) command. Using this, when the environment is active, you can just call:

```
add2virtualenv directory1 directory2 ...
```

to add the directories to your pythonpath for the current environment.

It handles autonomously the PATH changes on environment switches. No black magic required. Et voila!

Comment: I'm trying this out now, and I'll probably accept it in a couple of days if there still aren't any other solutions that do not depend on additional packages.

Comment: Its worth noting that you can automate this by editing the `postactivate` script in your virtualenvwrapper project folder.  By default this is found in `~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/postactivate` where "myproject" is the name of your virtual env.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the hacked version of `bin/activate` for reference. It sets the PYTHONPATH correctly, but unsetting does not work.

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi  

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
        hash -r
    fi  

    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1 
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi  

    if [ -n "$_OLD_PYTHONPATH" ] ; then
        PYTHONPATH="$_OLD_PYTHONPATH"
        export PYTHONPATH 
        unset _OLD_PYTHONPATH
    fi  

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset deactivate
    fi  
}

# unset irrelavent variables
deactivate nondestructive
VIRTUAL_ENV="env_location" # Anonymized
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
    # special case for Aspen magic directories
    # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
    PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
else
    PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
fi
export PS1

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
    hash -r
fi

_OLD_PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH"
PYTHONPATH="new_pythonpath" #Anonymized
export PYTHONPATH
```