# Is my virtual environment (python) causing my PYTHONPATH to break?

Tags: python, linux, unix, virtualenv

In my /etc/profile, I set PYTHONPATH as something.

But when I `source myvirtual-env`

And then do this in python:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

I don't see my paths anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the point of the virtualenv. It doesn't inherit from the rest of your setup. If you want a PYTHONPATH, you need to explicitly set one.

This [djangousers post](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/5316bd02d34b7544?pli=1) is probably helpful, you want to use [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to solve this problem.

More info in [this other SO post on a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969553/can-i-automatically-change-my-pythonpath-when-activating-deactivating-a-virtualen).

Comment: How do I set PYTHONPATH in my virtual environment?

Comment: using virtualenvwrapper and the add2virtualenv command. http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#path-management

Answer (score 0):

I don't observe the problem with Python 2.7, virtualenv 1.7.1.2 on Windows XP and I suspect Paul McMillan's answer is wrong.

```
# PYTHONPATH not set
# output from python -c "import sys; print sys.path" (edited for clarity)

'',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\DLLs',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info'

# PYTHONPATH not set, virtualenv activated
# output from python -c "import sys; print sys.path" (edited for clarity)

'',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\DLLs',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\plat-win',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\lib-tk',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\Scripts',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\Lib',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\DLLs',
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\Lib\\lib-tk',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7',
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages'

# PYTHONPATH set to c:\pythonpath_sample_dir
# output from python -c "import sys; print sys.path" (edited for clarity)

''
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg'
'c:\\pythonpath_sample_dir'   <--- value from PYTHONPATH
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\DLLs'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\plat-win'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\lib-tk'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info'

# PYTHONPATH set to c:\pythonpath_sample_dir, virtualenv activated
# output from python -c "import sys; print sys.path" (edited for clarity)

''
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg'
'c:\\pythonpath_sample_dir'   <--- value from PYTHONPATH
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\DLLs'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\plat-win'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\lib-tk'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\Scripts'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\Lib'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\DLLs'
'C:\\Program Files\\python\\2.7\\Lib\\lib-tk'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7'
'c:\\python\\virtualenv\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages'
```

Also [python virtualenv: why can I still import old modules in clean/new virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332270/python-virtualenv-why-can-i-still-import-old-modules-in-clean-new-virtualenv) seems to confirm `PYTHONPATH` **is being used** to construct `sys.path` also **when virtual environment is activated**.