# How do you set your pythonpath in an already-created virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux, unix, virtualenv

What file do I edit, and how? I created a virtual environment.

Comment: check that it points to the right directories. If you don't have one already, click the New button and create it.

Comment: Use the [add2virtualenv](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv) command.

Comment: add2virtualenv is a `virtualenvwrapper` command. It is not part of `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The most elegant solution to this problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184788/237059).

Original answer remains, but this is a messy solution:

---

If you want to change the `PYTHONPATH` used in a virtualenv, you can add the following line to your virtualenv's `bin/activate` file:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/the/path/you/want"
```

This way, the new `PYTHONPATH` will be set each time you use this virtualenv.

**EDIT:** *(to answer @RamRachum's comment)*

To have it restored to its original value on `deactivate`, you could add

```
export OLD_PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH"
```

before the previously mentioned line, and add the following line to your `bin/postdeactivate` script.

```
export PYTHONPATH="$OLD_PYTHONPATH"
```

Comment: Will it also be removed on `deactivate`?

Comment: So this means that a newly created virtual enviromnent have the default `PYTHONPATH` (the global one) instead of the virtualenv local path?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz `PYTHONPATH` is empty by default, it's just a way of augmenting the search paths available within `sys.path`. This method is only meant to have it modified for the time you're in a virtualenv.

Comment: This approach requires `VirtualEnvWrapper`

Comment: If you add this to your ~/.virtualenv/name_of_env/bin/activate file, it will load the pythonpath inside a virtualenv everytime you load it.

Comment: This worked very well for me, I am not using virtualenvwrapper. Only note is that I did not have such bin/postdeactivate script, rathere activate had a deactivate function. The line of code thus should be put there, being careful to wrap it in a if statement as the rest of the operations in the function.

Comment: I found that to get this working with `pyenv`, I needed to modify `~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/bin/pyenv-sh-activate` and `~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/bin/pyenv-sh-deactivate` rather than the virtualenv's activate and deactivate scripts. (which are called for all virtualenvs not just a specific one)

Comment: It seems odd that virtualenv doesn't do this by default.

Comment: One line fix: export PYTHONPATH="/the/path/you/want"

Comment: To expand @Niccolò comment (for newbies like me), the `if` statement inside `deactivate` can be `if true; then... fi`

Comment: Edit #2 is a lie! :) The right answer is [@arjen-p-de-vries's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184788/4228275)

Comment: How to add this change for windows. I have an `activate.bat` file

Comment: After looking a lot, that's what solved! Thanks

Answer (score 84):

You can create a `.pth` file that contains the directory to search for, and place it in the `{venv-root}/lib/{python-version}/site-packages` directory. E.g.:

```
cd $(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")
echo /some/library/path > some-library.pth
```

The effect is the same as adding `/some/library/path` to `sys.path`, and remain local to the `virtualenv` setup.

Comment: I really like this approach; not nearly as fickle as adding lines to activate/deactivate and doesn't require using virtualenvwrapper. If you'd rather not invoke python to find the site-packages dir, it's at the fairly-predictable path `$VIRTUALENV_ROOT/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. Docs on .pth files: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/site.html

Comment: I didn't want to type in an absolute path, because my workspaces move around my filesystem. And, my project path has spaces. So, I typed the slightly modified command:
```pushd "$(venv/bin/python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")"
...path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages ...path/to/project
echo ../../../../src > my_project.pth
popd```
Then I deactivated my virtualenv, and reactivated. I could now run project code that required knowing where my project directory was.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Modifying vendor-provided script (`/bin/activate`) is a malpractice and installing 3rd party tools is inferior to using built-in way to achieve the same.

Comment: Note for people trying to get this to work: you have to add an _existing_ filesystem path (it doesn't have to be a python module) or the path won't show up in `sys.path`. Quoting the docs: "For each of the distinct head-tail combinations, it sees if it refers to an existing directory, and if so, adds it to sys.path and also inspects the newly added path for configuration files."

Comment: But there is important difference between .pth and EXPORT approaches. EXPORT adds path to the beggining of the sys.path, but .pth adds to the end.

Comment: Great! As a minor comment, my 3.10 virtualenv says: `DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives` and `DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead`.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt, the path where you create the venv is hard coded in the activate script. So not sure how useful your dynamic approach really is.

Comment: @nilo Yes, the proper way of doing it nowadays is using `sysconfig` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638888/5984810). In a nutshell: `python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"`.

Comment: Note that the `.pth` file approach will add the path to the end of `sys.path` whereas fiddling with `PYTHONPATH` as in the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758351/5885546) gives you the ability to prioritize your desired path ahead of everything else.

Answer (score 78):

The comment by @s29 should be an answer:

One way to add a directory to the virtual environment is to install virtualenvwrapper (which is useful for many things) and then do

```
mkvirtualenv myenv
workon myenv
add2virtualenv . #for current directory
add2virtualenv ~/my/path
```

If you want to remove these path edit the file `myenvhomedir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth`

Documentation on virtualenvwrapper can be found at http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Specific documentation on this feature can be found at
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=add2virtualenv

Comment: to remove: `add2virtualenv -d`

Comment: just linked this answer in mine, as it is far better

Answer (score 4):

1. Initialize your virtualenv

```
cd venv

source bin/activate
```

2. Just set or change your python path by entering command following:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/home/django/srmvenv/lib/python3.4'
```

3. for checking python path enter in python:

```
   python

      \>\> import sys

      \>\> sys.path
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified my activate script to source the file `.virtualenvrc`, if it exists in the current directory, and to save/restore `PYTHONPATH` on activate/deactivate.

[You can find the patched `activate` script here.](https://gist.github.com/andrelaszlo/9444b42518a3fa55fa7d). It's a drop-in replacement for the activate script created by virtualenv 1.11.6.

Then I added something like this to my `.virtualenvrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH:+$PYTHONPATH:}/some/library/path"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers here really confused me. I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I found `pyvenv.cfg` at `venv/pyvenv.cfg`
the ENTIRE contents of that file was

```
home = C:\Users\User\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.7
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.7
```

all I did was change `\User` to `\NewUser` and that stopped the error
`No Python at 'C:\Users\User\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.6\python.exe'`

But yeah, I wasted an hour on this when ctrl+shift+f solved it easily.

Comment: Jumping between computers and storing my project in OneDrive caused an issue (differing usernames). Not a great solution but correcting the path here got me going.

Comment: In this case, I believe the intended solution is something like "make a new venv for every computer" ridiculous, I know, but that is modern computing for now.
It's called a URL, not a LRL.

Answer (score 0):

**The Simplest way I've seen to solving this is by doing the following,**

The python virtual environment PYTHON path is set in the "pyvenv.cfg" which is in the virtual environment folder.

```
home = C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0
```

include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11

you can edit this to your desired python version.
After I made the changes I had the same error I fixed this by creating a new "pyvenv.cfg" file with the new python path and replacing it with the existing one.
after deactivate your virtual environment and activate

this should work. at least it did for me

Answer (score -20):

It's already answered here -> [Is my virtual environment (python) causing my PYTHONPATH to break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686463/is-my-virtual-environment-python-causing-my-pythonpath-to-break)

## UNIX/LINUX

Add "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.0" this to ~/.bashrc file and source it by typing "source ~/.bashrc" OR ". ~/.bashrc".

## WINDOWS XP

1) Go to the Control panel
2) Double click System
3) Go to the Advanced tab
4) Click on Environment Variables

In the System Variables window, check if you have a variable named PYTHONPATH. If you have one already, check that it points to the right directories. If you don't have one already,  click the New button and create it.

## PYTHON CODE

Alternatively, you can also do below your code:-

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")
```

Comment: -1: This addresses the user's PYTHONPATH, not the virtualenv's PYTHONPATH.