# import error using djangorestframework with django-nonrel

Tags: django, python-2.7, importerror, django-nonrel, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a [Django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/) project using [Django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/#api-guide) and I've run into the following error after following the instructions in the Token Authorization section of their [Authorization API Guide](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html):

```
ImportError: No module named rest_framework.authtoken
```

Normally I would just assume that this is something to do with my PYTHONPATH but I don't think that's exactly what the problem is because I can import this framework from both IDLE and the project's shell run using manage.py, the latter both with and without a virtual environment. Within the virtual environment I have installed django and djangorestframework, which should be the only requiremnets for the project thus far.

I had thought that it might have been a Python versioning problem but given that I can import the package directly from the project's shell (running under the virtual env) I'm kind of at a loss since theoretically running manage.py from the same virtual environment should result in the same context for locating libraries.

I've spent a long time searching around trying to fix this issue but to no avail. Any suggestions? I'm happy to provide any additional information as needed!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

1. Are you sure you are using the directory one level above rest_framework in your PYTHONPATH?
2. Did you restart your shell after installation?
3. Take a look at [VirtualEnv PYTHONPATH setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv). Did you try setting the PYTHONPATH for virtualenv explicitly?