# syntax error after installing futures package in my virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenvwrapper, concurrent.futures

I'm using virtualenvwrapper. Under my `virtualenv` with python3, I installed `futures` successfully, then if I install anything else, it will pop up syntax errors which comes from `futures` package
errors are as follows:

```bash
$ pip install futures
Collecting futures
Installing collected packages: futures
Successfully installed futures-3.1.1
$ pip install sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pip._internal.wheel import Wheel
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 7, in <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.6/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/data/analytics/yliu/.virtualenvs/alice1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 381
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the answer in this question: [pip install error within Python 3 virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239805/pip-install-error-within-python-3-virtualenv), but it doesn't work for me. The `futures` package is indeed installed in the right version of python which is python 3.6.5.

I tried to install futures on python3.6 globally and everything works fine. so it seems something with the `futures` and the `virtualenv`.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks so much

Comment: The syntax of giving 3 parameters to `raise` is for Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement for the Python 3 syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue because there's a python3 package's requirement includes `futures`.
If you're short on time you can downgrade `setuptools` to 45.2.0 to bypass it.

Answer (score 2):

[futures package at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) is a backport of the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) standard library module to Python 2.

To use `futures` in Python 3 you don't need to install anything, it's a standard library module.

Now your virtualenv contains a broken Python 2 module. I recommend to remove the virtualenv and recreate it.