# Setting up Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I've been trying to set up the Object Detection environment.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

But I'm stuck at this line;

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

It spits out this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ImportError: No module named object_detection.builders
```

My system is;

```
MacOS Sierra
```

pip freeze > requirements.txt

```
altgraph==0.10.2
appnope==0.1.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bleach==1.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
certifi==2017.4.17
configparser==3.5.0
decorator==4.0.11
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
html5lib==0.9999999
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==5.4.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==6.0.0
Jinja2==2.9.6
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.1
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
lxml==3.8.0
macholib==1.5.1
Markdown==2.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
mistune==0.7.4
mock==2.0.0
modulegraph==0.10.4
nbconvert==5.2.1
nbformat==4.3.0
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.0.0
numpy==1.13.0
olefile==0.44
pandocfilters==1.4.1
pathlib2==2.3.0
pbr==3.1.1
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==4.1.1
prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
protobuf==3.3.0
ptyprocess==0.5.1
py2app==0.7.3
Pygments==2.2.0
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2013.7
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.3.0
scandir==1.5
scipy==0.13.0b1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.2.0
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
widgetsnbextension==2.0.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

If somebody has a clue, please.

**Edit 1**

I'm using virtualenv and I couldn't find the tensorflow/models/ directory;

```
(objectDetects) $ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.2.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /tensorflow/objectDetects/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: bleach, werkzeug, html5lib, six, markdown, backports.weakref, wheel, numpy, mock, protobuf
```

So I tried to export it from the root folder, and it spits out a new error;

```
(objectDetects) $ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
(objectDetects) $ python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/tensorflow/objectDetects/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "/tensorflow/objectDetects/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
ImportError: No module named nets
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding libraries to python path.
Run the following command from tensorflow/models directory.

```
# From tensorflow/models/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Now the code will run successfully.This command needs to run from every new terminal you start. If you wish to avoid running this manually, you can add it as a new line to the end of your ~/.bashrc file.

For more info check [installation link](https://github.com/datitran/Object-Detector-App/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) : Adding Libraries to PYTHON PATH section.

Comment: I'm using virtualevn so I couldn't find the tensorflow/models directory. (Please see the new edit on the original post)

Comment: If you want to change the `PYTHONPATH` used in a `virtualenv`, you can add the following line to your virtualenv's `bin/activate` file: `export PYTHONPATH="/the/path/you/want" `  For more details [this link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error every time you can add PYTHONPATH to your ~/.bashrc file. Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/tensorAI/59a6173a7b6a061dd417fadb3894eeb0) for the reference.

```
LOCAL_DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
var=$(printf 'export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:%s/slim"' "$LOCAL_DIR")
echo $var >> ~/.bashrc
```

run the above lines from `tensorflow/models/research/` then run the line below from the same directory.

`python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.