# pytest 'No module named ...' for import within the tested module

Tags: python, flask, pytest, importerror, pythonpath

I found some questions that are similar but did not quite solve my problem (e.g. [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada?rq=1))

My project is structured as follows:

```
MyApp
 |
 +--MyApp
 |   |
 |   +--__init__.py
 |   +--app.py
 |   +--config.py
 |
 +--tests
     |
     +--__init__.py
     +--test_app.py
```

in my test_app.py I import app.py, which works just fine.

`from MyApp import app`

but within app.py I import config.py like this.

`import config`

With this setup I can run the app module, but pytest fails to import 'config' and raises:

`ImportError: No module named 'config'`

pytest succeeds when I change the import statement in app.py to:

`from MyApp import config`

However, an error is raised when I try to run the app:

`ImportError: No module named 'MyApp'`

From reading other questions I'm confident that there is something wrong with the `PYTHONPATH`, I just could not figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

set the PYTHONPATH variable to root folder of your project and set all other paths relative to this

Within same folder you use

**import module**

If referring from other folder you use

***from module import class***

change the references in your project as above and it should be resolved

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I still run into the same problem. I set the PYTHONPATH within my virtualenv to the root folder (following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv)), but the result is the same.

Comment: I found a solution that works but does not seem to be very elegant: I added `import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'MyApp'))` in test_app.py before importing 'app.py'. Is there a more elegant way?