# virtual env PYTHONPATH using tox

Tags: python, tox

I have a tox.ini file

```
[testenv:py27]
deps= -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}{:}{toxinidir}/helpers
```

I ran the command `tox` and the virtualenv was created inside `.tox/py27`

When I activate the py27 environment

```
cd .tox/py7/bin
source activate 
py27 $ echo $PYTHONPATH < gives null>
```

`PYTHONPATH` is empty though the tox.ini has `setenv` with `PYTHONPATH` explicity set

Why is the PYTHONPATH setting itself to empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you expecting tox to modify the `activate` script like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758351/2626627)?

> If you want to change the `PYTHONPATH` used in a virtualenv, you can add the following line to your virtualenv's `bin/activate` file:
>
> ```
> export PYTHONPATH="/the/path/you/want"
> ```
>
> This way, the new `PYTHONPATH` will be set each time you use this virtualenv.

If yes: tox does not do anything like that - it creates a vanilla virtualenv (or venv if tox-venv is installed).

So, what is defined in `setenv` only happens, when you run the tox environment (see [code](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/28e3191e6e327aa1201008116fac1657701b67a3/src/tox/venv.py#L366)).