# Installing my own python module inside a virtual environment

Tags: python, module, virtualenv

**What I have:**

- local Python3 files that I want to turn into a module `test_module`
- `test_module` folder containing an empty `__init__.py`, a `setup.py` file (see below) and subdirectories with several source
  files

**What I want:**

1. continuously work on and improve `test_module` locally
2. have an easy way to install `test_module` and all its dependencies locally in my own virtual environment (created using `python3 -m venv my_environment`)
3. run files that make use of the module via `python myexample.py`, without having to take care of adapting my local PYTHONPATH variable each time i enter or exit the `my_environment`
4. share my python code with others via git, and allow them to install their code locally on their machines using the same procedure (as simple as possible)
5. learn best practices on how to create my own module

**How I'm doing it at the moment:**

- `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` for installing dependencies
- adding `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:."` to `my_environment/bin/activate`, to have my own module in the search path
  (as found here: [How do you set your pythonpath in an already-created virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv))

I'd like to know if there are "cleaner" solutions based on `setup.py`, possibly involving something like `pip install ./test_module` or similar that takes care of 2.-3. automagically.

My current `setup.py` file looks as follows

```
 from setuptools import setup

 setup(
    name='test_module',
    version='0.1',
    description='Some really good stuff, that I am still working on',
    author='Bud Spencer',
    author_email='bud.spencer@stackoverflow.com',
    packages=['test_module'],  # same as name
    install_requires=['numpy', 'scipy', 'sklearn', 'argparse'], # external packages as dependencies
  )
```

Comment: why you decided to share python package with others via git? why you can't just upload package into `pypi`? I think that `pip install test_module` is eases way.

Comment: I am not very familiar with `pypi`, so I didn't even consider it. But as of now, I only want to share the package wit ha couple of collaborators for development, not with everyone. And git seemed to be the natural choice for that, particularly since the project was started on git in the first place.

Comment: ok. could you explain details? don't understand the problem. you can run all functionality without installing package into `virtualenv`. I mean it would be something like this: `git clone...` + `virtualenv env` + `source env/bin/activate` + `pip install -r requirements.txt` + `python run something`. Besides, you do not need to do cloning and installing twice. don't understand for what install package into `virtualenv`. I mean if you need to share package `pip + virtualenv` is good way. But I'm not sure that you need it.

Comment: The main point is that `test_module` is my own module, i.e. it only exists locally. As far as I understand, I cannot install such modules using `pip`. If there is such a way, I'd like to know how to do it (that is one part of the question).
Right now, the way I make it work is to add `export PYTHONPATH...` to my `bin/activate` script, but this feels a little hacky and I'm thinking there must be a better way, without me having to ask other people to mess with their `activate` script to run my code in their `virtualenv`

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use PyPI. anyway you can install package into any `virtualenv` using `setup.py`. `source env/bin/activate`, `cd path_to_your_repo`, `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to run `pip install -e <path/url>` from within your virtual env, which will install a package (with a `setup.py` file as you have) from either a local path or a Git repo. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support for an explanation on the syntax of the latter.

Example:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/me/test_module/#egg=test-module
```

If you have already installed and want to pull the latest code from the repo, add an `--upgrade` switch to the above.

Comment: thanks, what if the repo is private?