# How to add local python files as a library to python virtual environment the same way as pip install to Airflow Docker

Tags: python, docker, airflow, virtualenv

- How to install my own python package to python virtual environment?
- Final goal would be to add that package to a Airflow Docker environment.
- My Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest-python3.8
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483981/11609051 for the installation of your package to the venv.

After that you need to extend your docker image.
For this your Dockerfile.txt should be similar to:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.0
WORKDIR /Users/Desktop/tools/airflow2.4-lite
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt
```

then you need to run command:

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile.txt --tag updated_image
```

Then you need to change your Airflow image name in your docker-compose.yaml file as updated_image :

```
image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-extending_airflow:latest}
```

and run the commands:

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
docker-compose up -d --build airflow-webserver airflow-scheduler
```

After this rebuilt you can use the standard command for standing containers up:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

You can check the if packages are installed via this simple dag:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'foo',
    'retry': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}


with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="checker_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 27),
    schedule_interval='@daily'
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
      task_id="pip_task",
      bash_command='pip freeze',
  )
    
    task2 = BashOperator(
      task_id="printenv_task",
      bash_command='printenv',
  )

    task3 = BashOperator(
      task_id="apt_task",
      bash_command='apt list --installed',
  )

    task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

However there are some points that need to be taken into account:

- Your requirements.txt file should be in your Airflow Docker project file.
- Any of your packages in your venv shouldn't have the dependency of Python greater than of your Airflow's which is Python 3.8 nor they shouldn't depend on a package that uses a dependent rely on greater than Python 3.8 .
- For the above you can use the Homebrew's Python@3.8 and you can install the packages in site-packages directory with: `pip3.8 install <package-name>` command.