# How to add a PYTHONPATH in a virtual environment with brew on a Mac?

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, pythonpath

I am running macOS Mojave and I have installed Python 3.7 following this blog post [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos).

In short, what I did:

1. Installed Xcode
2. Set up Homebrew
3. Installed Python 3
4. Created a virtual environment

All following the steps in the article.

I now created a python file with some functions.
I know that to use this file in a jupyter notebook as `import my_file`, I need to have the path to this file added in a `PYTHONPATH` usually done in the `.bash_profile`. Even though I did added `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/my/files/folder/:$PYTHONPATH"`, nothing happened.

My question is: How can I add a custom PYTHONPATH, so that I can import the file in `jupyter` or `ipython`?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot a $

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/your/path/to/your/module
```

Comment: Should this be in the `.bash_profile`? If yes, does this affect only my virtual environment or all of them? Final question, why do I need to add `$PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I guess for a virtualenv you might have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17963979/7692655

Comment: do you source your bashrc? with 'source .bash_profile'?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same env too you, and there are some ways to solve it.

**First**, you can edit the sys.path using the sys.path.append() **--Not recommended**

> import sys
>
> import sys.path.append('/your/work/path')

**Second**, you can edit **PYTHONPATH** in "~/.bash_profile", but it will not work when you use the IDEA, such as Pycharm.

> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/your/work/path
>
> source ~/.bash_profile

**Last**,you can just copy your work directory to **dist-packages** which you can find it using **sys.path**.

Also, you can find some other ways from  [Add to python path mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x)

Comment: Why do you use `sys.path` afterwards?

Comment: check the config whether works . it will print all the directory

Comment: It does not work. Also it makes no sense to edit `PYTHONPATH` and then use `sys.path`. You can see here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x

Comment: I check the ipython/python/jupyter in terminal, actually it does works.  But while i use the IDE(pycharm), it seems doesn't  get the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

In my installation, `/usr/local/bin/ipython` was a script containing

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/bin/ipython" "$@"`.
```

Changing this to

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.5.0/libexec/bin/ipython" "$@"
```

did the trick for me.