# Why do I need to include sys.path.append to import a module with Python 3.6 and my colleges doesn't need?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

I have been facing a weird situation for some months now.

In the several codes I have been working, to import a module in python 3.6.9, Ubuntu 18.04, such as:

`import src.Modules.ABC.DC as DC`

I do need to include `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '..'))` 
but all my colleges at work using the same code and virtual environment just does not need that line.

If it helps, in the terminal, if I do not include that line it returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Consequently, my questions are:

1-Why do I need to include that line and in a different computer I does not need?

2-Do you suggested to always include that line to have a more reliable code?

The folder structure is something like:

```
Myproject/src/Modules/ABC/DE

Myproject/tests/Modules/ABC/test_DE
```

I created a virtual env at Myproject, at src, tests and so on. And it returns always the same.
When I run without a venv it also returns the same problem. The python command I use is

`python3 tests/Modules/ABC/test_DE.py`

This is just annoying since I always need to remove that line to request a merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to (the full path to) `Myproject`.  That tells Python where to find modules to import, and it works regardless of which directory you run the script from.  This avoids the need to modify `sys.path`.

Comment: Thank you! It helps to solve the problem. I used the following procedure to change the virtual env PYTHONPATH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv

Comment: One aspect that keeps intriguing me is, that when I run `echo $PYTHONPATH` in their computer it does not return the path to the modules.