# Python inside a virtualenv is broken (Django)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

TL;DR - Microsoft Store Apps are broken (0 bytes), hence the Python interpreter is unable to create process and run "Python" inside virtualenv, I failed to follow numerous explanations of how to change virtualenv path for Python.

Recently, without any changes to my computer/environment, an issue started occurring when executing (also tried python3, which brings the same):

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This brought back the following issue:

> Unable to create process using
> '"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"'

As I dug deeper, I realized that all of the apps installed under this folder are 0 bytes, hence they are completed broken, all of a sudden.
Therefore I figured it's not an issue with Django, rather the python itself.

I tried changing the virtualenv path for Python.exe, instead of using WindowsApps version, I installed the original Python from the original website.

I failed to do so, multiple times.

I tried: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757178/how-do-you-set-your-pythonpath-in-an-already-created-virtualenv/47184788#47184788" - Adding the path inside "activate" and "activate.bat", as

```
set PYTHONPATH="C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
```

And the issue persists.

I tried every solution/article I found in regards to the issue I have. Many of them claim a simple result, whereas the rest claim a complete refactor is required.
Even downloading from Microsoft store is broken, it always fails.

Since I'm unable to remove the broken apps, and I wasn't able to find a way to change the virtualenv Python interpreter, I am here, asking for your assistance.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's usually a lot easier to rebuild your virtual environment than to try to fix it. Are all of your dependencies declared, e.g. in a `requirements.txt` (for pip), `pyproject.toml` (for Poetry), or `Pipfile` (for Pipenv)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed python from python.org, ensure that it has been properly added to the `PATH` and you're not inadvertently using the windows store version.

> 1. Open command prompt
> 2. Execute `where python` to check which python your system is using.
>
> [image: where python example]

If you're only seeing the WindowsApps version of python listed in the output of `where` command, then python installer apparently didn't add the location to `PATH`, so [you'll need to manually add it yourself.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6318156/4670905)

Also, if you're not restricted to use virtualenv, you can give [conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html)  a try.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I do see the recently-installed python 3.10 in the PATH.
The WindowsApps version is (apparently) attached to the virtualenv of the Django project I have. 
And it still won't work...  
In regards to Conda, I'll try giving it a shot, if there's an easy way to convert projects

Comment: Why are you referencing Anaconda when OP is using Python from `python.org` (which you explicitly state in your answer)? @Spytolie, there is absolutely _no need_ to switch to Anaconda.

Comment: @Spytolie You can try creating a `requirements.txt` file manually and add only the necessary dependencies for your project there (e.g django, psycopg2). Then you can do `pip install -r requirements.txt` and pip will automatically install any additional dependencies.

Also, in your original question, I believe you're trying to use `PYTHONPATH` incorrectly. The purpose of  `PYTHONPATH` isn't to point to python binary, it's used by python itself to look for modules. More info: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: Hello @Zyrif, just to make sure I understood correctly, this suggestion refers to a complete re-build of the virtual environment, just with the correct Python path, is that correct?

Comment: @Spytolie Yes, since that is the least convoluted way to use a different python interpreter than the one used to create it, and to re-create the environment, you need a working system python, hence my answer. 

Also, When you create an environment using virtualenv, the python interpreter (python.exe) is **_copied_**, not symlinked. So it's more like the correct python interpreter _copy_, rather than the correct interpreter _path_. When you create the virtual environment using the python.org distribution, it'll automatically include the python.org version of the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As I began rebuilding, I figured it out.

When building a virtualenv, the python I used was directing to:

> "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"'

Python interpreter is saved as the "**PATH**" to execute python.
Since my Python interpreter from Microsoft Store went broke, I was unable to execute python inside the virtual environment.

- **Venv configures a file called:**

> pyvenv.cfg

This is how the virtual environment knows what Python interpreter to use.
**Inside it, the first line states:**

> home = C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\

Therefore, we just need to re-configure it to the new path of Python interpreter:

> home = C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

And it worked for me.

Thanks for everyone's assistant, glad it's done.