# python virtualenv: why can I still import old modules in clean/new virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm starting a new Python project, and I want to work with **virtualenv** to have a clean start. After setting one up though, I can still import old modules that I have not installed for the new virtualenv - why?

I created one with:

```
virtualenv ~/virtualenvs/mynewproject --no-site-packages
```

now i activate with `source bin/activate`

Now when I start a python interpreter (by just typing `python`), I thought that it will use the python interpreter in my virtualenv, and my pythonpath would have been set to the site-packages path of my virutalenv's python (/virtualenvs/mynewporject/lib/python2.7/site-packages), and nothing else.

However, when I look at sys.path, all the old, system-wide packages are available, and I can import them fine - which is what I don't want.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `which python` show?

Comment: which python shows the virtual env python: ~/virtualenvs/mynewproject/bin/python

Comment: do you use screen/byobu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable which probably points to where you have the older version of your package. This variable always comes first in your `sys.path` so make sure you either clear it or change it to point to the virtualenv which you activate.